# Cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type int64

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have struct

```
type tySurvey struct {
    Id     int64            `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name   string           `json:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

I do `json.Marshal` write JSON bytes in HTML page. jQuery modifies `name` field in object and encodes object using jQueries `JSON.stringify` and jQuery posts string to Go handler.

`id` field encoded as string.

Sent: `{"id":1}` Received: `{"id":"1"}`

Problem is that `json.Unmarshal` fails to unmarshal that JSON because `id` is not integer anymore.

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type int64
```

What is best way to handle such data? I do not wish to manually convert every field. I wish to write compact, bug free code.

Quotes is not too bad. JavaScript does not work well with int64.

I would like to learn the easy way to unmarshal json with string values in int64 values.

Comment: Is there a way to know which field causes the problem ?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

This is handled by adding `,string` to your tag as follows:

```
type tySurvey struct {
   Id   int64  `json:"id,string,omitempty"`
   Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

This can be found about halfway through the documentation for [Marshal](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).

Please note that you cannot decode the empty string by specifying `omitempty` as it is only used when encoding.

Comment: This would work if `id` does not come in as integer. Otherwise, you'd get an error "invalid use of ,string struct tag..."

Comment: Using `,string` wouldn't work if the field come in either int or string. The program will nag at you for using it on an int field. Use `json.Number` struct tag instead solve the issue as pointed by the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64044324/534862

Answer (score 25):

use `json.Number`

```
type tySurvey struct {
    Id     json.Number      `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name   string           `json:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. the accepted answer doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a type alias for int or int64 and create a custom json unmarshaler
Sample code:

[Reference](https://kenyaappexperts.com/blog/golang-cannot-unmarshal-string-into-go-value-of-type-int/)

```
// StringInt create a type alias for type int
type StringInt int

// UnmarshalJSON create a custom unmarshal for the StringInt
/// this helps us check the type of our value before unmarshalling it

func (st *StringInt) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    //convert the bytes into an interface
    //this will help us check the type of our value
    //if it is a string that can be converted into a int we convert it
    ///otherwise we return an error
    var item interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &item); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    switch v := item.(type) {
    case int:
        *st = StringInt(v)
    case float64:
        *st = StringInt(int(v))
    case string:
        ///here convert the string into
        ///an integer
        i, err := strconv.Atoi(v)
        if err != nil {
            ///the string might not be of integer type
            ///so return an error
            return err

        }
        *st = StringInt(i)

    }
    return nil
}

func main() {

    type Item struct {
        Name   string    `json:"name"`
        ItemId StringInt `json:"item_id"`
    }
    jsonData := []byte(`{"name":"item 1","item_id":"30"}`)
    var item Item
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &item)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", item)

}
```